# Condition Text Color change for ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let goal of goals" >
 <ion-card color="mint">
  <br>
  <h2 text-center>{{goal.name}}</h2> 
  <button ion-button [navPush] ="budget" full clear text-center (click)="viewGoal(goal.name, 
   goal.amount , goal.startDate, goal.endDate, goal.optional, goal.goals_id)" >

  <h1 ><span style="font-size:large;"> $ </span>{{(totalExps[goal.goals_id] == undefined) ? 0 : 
  (totalExps[goal.goals_id])}} of $ {{goal.amount}}</h1>

  </button>

 <p text-center>$ {{(totalExps[goal.goals_id] == undefined) ? goal.amount : (goal.amount - 
  totalExps[goal.goals_id])}} till budget is reached!</p>

 </ion-card>
```

I want to change the text colour for the total expense when the amount is greater than the goal amount.

Comment: can you share your code via stackblitz? and also please highlight which specific text tag you wanted to turn red? the last paragraph or?

Comment: I want to turn this red  (totalExps[goal.goals_id])

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `ngStyle` or `ngClass` angular directives to achieve this.

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>
```

Example

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':person.country === 'UK' ? 'green' : 'red' }"></<div>
```

[Tutorial for explanation](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/)
[Official Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)